# how to enter two list views which is inside one row which is already inside the column in flutter

Tags: flutter, listview, row

i have a situation in which i have to do like this [image: Column-> Row-> Two List Views]

i have tried many solutions but unable to store is it possible??

```
Expanded(
  child: Row(
    // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
    children: [
      ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: selectedMainCasteIds?.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Text('${selectedMainCasteIds![index].mainCasteName}',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10),);
        },
      ),
      Text('ddddd'),

      ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: selectedMainCasteIds?.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Text('${selectedMainCasteIds![index].mainCasteName}',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10),);
        },
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

wrap you `Listview` with `Expanded` too.

```
Expanded(
  child: Row(
    // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
    children: [
      Expanded(
        child: ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: 2,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Text(
              'lorem ipsum dolor',
//                     style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
      Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
        child: Text('ddddd'),
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: 2,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Text(
              'lorem ipsum dolor',
              textAlign: TextAlign.right,
//                     style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```dart
final techs = <String>['Dart', 'Flutter', 'Firebase'];
final packages = <String>['Freezed', 'Riverpod', 'Isar'];

Column(
  children: [
    Row(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: techs.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Text('Tech - ${techs[index]}');
            },
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: packages.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Text('Package - ${packages[index]}');
            },
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ],
),
```

**Output:**

[image: result]